# Is it recommended to pass setters from useState as props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently in a coding bootcamp and the instructor told me that it is not best practice to pass the setters defined in my useState as props to children components. Is this true? and if so, why?

Comment: It is not a good idea, because when the project grows larger, it will turn into a maintenance nightmare, it's better to use state management tools like redux and redux-toolkits. Additionally, if you want to share the same setter across different components, you will have to keep moving it up, until it's the parent of both those components, it's fine for a small project, but imagine what happens in the large scale, you will be passing around so many props that you will even forget what the application does and just manage the props

Comment: on my learning track, i am 4 chapters away from learning Redux, so it will probably make more sense to me once I get there, thank you for your in-depth answer however.

Comment: Redux, on the surface will look over complicated, and you will be tempted to pass the setter as a prop, you will only realize it was huge mistake only after the project really grows in size. Both of them can be use together, but it's strongly recommended to use redux just for maintenance in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's ok to pass the setters down! Especially in small applications, it is very useful.

But In my experience when the app grows, it's better to use some kind of state management, like redux, recoil, context, and so on.

Also, in my opinion, in some cases will be very good to create a custom function like `addUser` or something similar to prevent passing so many states down, maintaining more the logic on the parent component.

Comment: I don't see any reason why `function changeState(value) { setState(value) }` would be an improvement on using `setState` directly. I see a few reasons how it's worse though (like the identity of the function).

Comment: @Bergi But a function `changeState` is very auto named documented, you certainly will know what the function does. it's better pass 4 custom functions that make something at its correct component scope than pass like 4 setStates down a child component and then it takes care of the logic.

Comment: If `changeState` only does `setState`, then I'd prefer to name it `setState`. And of course you can also do `const [state, changeState] = useState()` if you prefer that unusual name. Also yes, you would do `<ChildComponent onChangeState={setState} />` instead of naming the prop `setState`. But I'm not sure what you mean by "*pass 4 custom functions that make something at its correct component scope*" - there is no logic to take care of, there's just a state to be set.

Comment: @Bergi You showed me a lot of bad code practices to explain your point. That's not what I'm talking about here, when I say it's better not to pass setters and passing a custom function is just a (cleaner in my opinion) way to perform an action, usually setting a state is related to a greater sense, we set the state to submit a form, or delete a user, or add a post, that's what I'm talking about. What usually happens is that devs pass 60 setters instead of passing 2 functions. I'm not saying it's a crime to pass a state down, I did it many times! I just saying when systems grow it's sucks.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer then to expand on "*it's better to create a custom function like `changeState`*" (especially when you *don't* mean `changeState` but rather `submitForm` or `deleteUser` or `addPost`)? Maybe I was just playing devil's advocate, but maybe you should clarify in your answer what you mean by "function".

Comment: "*devs pass 60 setters instead of passing 2 functions*" - my experience would be the opposite. In a well-designed (including large) application you have fewer states and more "functions" (actions). E.g. both `addUser` and `removeUser` would act on the same `users` state. Or you `useReducer` instead of `useState` and have only one dispatcher for multiple actions.

Comment: @Bergi Okay, I'll edit my answer to be cleaner, I understand your point of view, if you have something you think that can improve my answer I am open to it. Thanks!